# Showing two same favourite questions?

Tags: discussion, bug

When I was looking for my favorite listed [question](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1430492/vusan?tab=favorites), its showing two same result.

Favorite question with two same result is:
**How to know the current state of mouse button(mouseup state or mousedown state)?**
Any idea on it?

Comment: Did you favourite it, unfavourite it and then favourite it again?  Hmm, the [timeline](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/12191743/timeline) of that post doesn't show favorites...

Comment: I forget as I favourite it about year ago.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to have managed to favourite that question twice as can be seen from [this SEDE Query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/183791/votes-on-a-post-by-users?PostId=12191743&VoteTypeId=5)

The first time was on Aug, 30th 2012 and once more on Sep, 19th 2012.

You are not the only one as can be seen [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/183615/questions-favorited-multiple-times-by-the-same-users).

1413 users have favorited the same question multiple times. User [The Noble Coder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1067051/thenoble-coder) managed to do that 10 times on a couple of questions.

I consider this to be a bug that should be fixed in 6-8 weeks.

Comment: Re query edit: I tolerated the misspellings. I tolerated the inconsistent spacing. I tolerated the overuse of lowercase. But the ordinal in the `ORDER BY` was more than I could bear.

Comment: There are days that I'm just a lazy bastard :-)

Comment: Nah, it's a plural bug (well, plural rows in the same table bug, anyway...) so it will never be fixed.

Comment: I hope the Giant S stays in Jeffs closet...